# Java Vaadin combobox warning Intellij : unclear if a varargs or non-varargs call is desired

Tags: java, intellij-idea, combobox, vaadin

My code is working, but I've got a warning from Intelij (code gets highlighted) : `unclear if a varargs or non-varargs call is desired`.
But code does perfect what I want or what I expect, fill the combo with the values.
When I click on the item in the combo, it returns me right enum 
So anyone can help me to fix this warning.

```
  ComboBox comboStatus = new ComboBox();
  comboStatus.addItems(BatchStatusCode.values());
```

The warning is on the second line
Where BatchStatusCode is a relative simple enum

```
public enum BatchStatusCode {

    RUNNING("R","RUNNING"),
    FINISHED("F","FINISHED"),
    CANCELED("C","CANCELED");
    .... some code

    BatchStatusCode(final String code,final String fullName) {
        this.code = code;this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public String getFullName() { return fullName;}
    .... some code
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it was duplicated in my copy paste. I edited my post. The warning is still there.

Comment: No problem.  I would check out [this](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/5241) bug in the framework.  If you're using an affected version of vaadin (note: very old), then there are two methods, one which takes an `Object`, and one which takes a varargs.  I believe the warning is stating it is unclear which one you're calling in this context.  If you explicitly cast to `Object[]` in your call, does the warning go away?

Comment: What Vaadin version are we talking about?

Comment: Hello, it's Vaadin 7 , thanks for asking.

Comment: When I did cast it to Object, I only got the name of the enum class in the ComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Vaadin 7 seems to be the only one version having this method, so my assumption is that you are using it. Please, correct me, if I am wrong*

The error states that compiler is not sure what method exactly you would like to use. Is it the one taking the variable amount of parameters or the one taking only one.

There are two overloaded methods in the `AbstractSelect` class for the [`addItems`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.7.17/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#addItems-java.util.Collection-):

1. `public void addItems(Collection<?> itemIds) throws UnsupportedOperationException`
2. `public void addItems(Object... itemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException`

So, solution could be simply ignore the warning or make it explicit to the compiler  what method you would like to use. For example, like this : 
`comboBox.addItems(Arrays.asList(BatchStatusCode.values()));`

---

Edit: This is not the cause, actually. But I will leave it here

The *problem* with the `Enum`'s `values()` is that it's generated by the compiler [when it creates an enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates an enum.
For example, they have a static values method that returns an array containing all
of the values of the enum in the order they are declared.
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution with ```Arrays.asList``` worked